# How do I see what element an iterator is pointing to in an vector with vscode using gdb?

Tags: c++, gdb, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm trying out VSCode writing some C++ using gdb, and I am finding that I need to determine what element an `iterator` is pointing at for a particular `vector`.  Is there some way of doing this?

Comment: You can find that in the documentation (https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/). Look up the `print` command.

Comment: in the watch you can use the `dist???()` function to calculate the distance between iterators, that is the index

Comment: @rioV8, can you please post an example?  I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to do this as part of your program, you can use STL:

```
int distance = std::distance(begin(s), result);
```

If you're trying to do this using the watch window in VSCode, the above will not work, as it's calling a function.  Since the underlying structure of a vector is an array, you can use math instead.  In the watch window, add:

```
(&(*myIterator) - &(myVector[0])) / sizeof(myVector[0])
```